# How state variable change affects blocks in blockchain?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions

When a state variable is updated, is a new block mined with the new value and then spread over the network? or the value is overwritten. I know that once the block is mined it can never be changed but when I was working in a project, I updated some values and everytime it returned the latest change when fetched.
And if new block is mined with a new value of state variable, how will I get the old data.
(I was using thirdweb in my project).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when a state variable is updated, a new block gets mined with the updated value. Blockchain only stores the current state of a smart contract. As the blockchain state is updated, the history of past values were not directly accessible. Hence we emit the events to keep track of previous values.

Comment: Okay got it, thanks a lot <3.